# Nginx remove request in redirects

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have the redirect rules:

```
location /aanbod.html?limit=all {return 301 https://www.site.nl/compleet/ ;}
```

This rule redirects but leave ?limit=all request

How to remove it and get new URL without a request?

Thaks!

Answer (score 2):

First, nginx `location` directive matches only the normalized URI of the request, that is, the `?limit=all` does nothing in your rule.

In order to remove the query arguments from the 301 redirect, use this:

```
return 301 https://www.site.nl/compleet/?
```